# Sampling a Dice to test its Fairness

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

I'm kind of stumped on this one. I have a dice that I have rolled, 50, 100, and 200 times respectively, and recorded down the number of times that a 1-6 have landed. Now that I've done this, the goal is to plot the probability of each side  with a 95% confidence interval. How am I supposed to calculate separate confidence intervals for the individual sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual side:

For 1,  you count how many times you got side 1. Let’s say the number = $n_1$, and the total trial (how many times you threw a die)=$N$

The sample proportion of side 1, $\bar p_1=\frac{n_1}{N}$
Standard Deviation of the sample proportions $ \sigma_{\bar{p_1}} =\sqrt{\frac{\bar{p_1}(1-\bar {p_1})}{N}}$

Margin of Error, $E=z_{95\%} \sigma_{\bar{p_1}} $

Repeat side 2,3,4,5, and 6